# Permission Denied docker Mac Os M1

Tags: python, macos, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm extremely new to docker and I keep running into "permission denied" issues. I was able to build an image using the following docker file:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Python

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
    apt-get install python-opencv -y &&\
    pip install -U pip setuptools

RUN pip install keras jupyter && \
    pip install ipdb pytest pytest-cov python-coveralls coverage==3.7.1 pytest-xdist pep8 pytest-pep8 pydot_ng jupyter && \
    pip install Pillow scikit-learn notebook matplotlib nose pyyaml six h5py pandas scikit-image python-resize-image glob2 && \
    pip install opencv-python && \
    pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu tensorflow-probability

# COPY ST2inJupyter.js ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js #this does not work.  put explicit abs path on image (abs path for files in directories outside Dockerfile do not work currently)
# Set up our notebook config.

COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /root/.jupyter/
ADD startup /src/startup

ENV PYTHONPATH='/src/:$PYTHONPATH'

WORKDIR /src

#Configure Jupyter notebook port exposure
EXPOSE 8888

# For CUDA profiling, TensorFlow requires CUPTI.
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH \usr\local\cuda\extras\CUPTI\lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# TensorBoard (only needed for visualizing lower level TF models.  in keras, not really too helpful, but just keep in)
EXPOSE 6006

# Define startup bash script in external file (loaded via ADD or COPY above)
CMD /src/startup
```

When I run the docker image: `docker run -v ${PWD}:/src/hostpwd -it -p 8888:8888 [image_name]`, I consistently keep getting the the "Permission Denied" Error. Here is what it looks like:

`/bin/sh: 1: /src/startup: Permission denied`

Can anyone help me solve this issue? I have a Mac OS and I have the preview version of docker for the new M1 chip.

Comment: Did you set the execution bit on `/src/setup`?

Comment: I think so. Every file should have permissions. 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nidhigthite  staff  1335 Jan 26 18:21 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nidhigthite  staff  1324 Jan 25 10:55 jupyter_notebook_config.py
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 nidhigthite  staff   253 Jan 25 10:55 startup

Comment: What happens if you `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of backslashes?

Comment: It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From comments, working code as shown below

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Python

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
    apt-get install python-opencv -y &&\
    pip install -U pip setuptools

RUN pip install keras jupyter && \
    pip install ipdb pytest pytest-cov python-coveralls coverage==3.7.1 pytest-xdist pep8 pytest-pep8 pydot_ng jupyter && \
    pip install Pillow scikit-learn notebook matplotlib nose pyyaml six h5py pandas scikit-image python-resize-image glob2 && \
    pip install opencv-python && \
    pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu tensorflow-probability

# COPY ST2inJupyter.js ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js #this does not work.  put explicit abs path on image (abs path for files in directories outside Dockerfile do not work currently)
# Set up our notebook config.

COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /root/.jupyter/
ADD startup /src/startup

ENV PYTHONPATH='/src/:$PYTHONPATH'

WORKDIR /src

#Configure Jupyter notebook port exposure
EXPOSE 8888

# For CUDA profiling, TensorFlow requires CUPTI.
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# TensorBoard (only needed for visualizing lower level TF models.  in keras, not really too helpful, but just keep in)
EXPOSE 6006

# Define startup bash script in external file (loaded via ADD or COPY above)
CMD /src/startup
```

(paraphrased from chepner)